# ElasticSearch get documents by field values contains/includes

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get docs from elastic search by fields includes/contains dynamic text.
Example:
Got those documents in elastic

```
{
id: 12345,
name: test66,
description: 'some desc231431',
entity_id 9201a22asdasdadbfbfe3642994,
entity: entity1,
tag_ids: [],
owners: [],
account_id: asd1233124124,
integration_type: integartionType1
}

{
id: 12345,
name: name2,
description: 'some desc',
entity_id 9201a22asdasdadbfbfe3642994,
entity: entity1,
tag_ids: ['123445','sadx'],
owners: [],
account_id: asd1233124124,
integration_type: integartionType1
}

{
id: 12345,
name: name3,
description: 'this is test !!!!',
entity_id 9201a22asdasdadbfbfe3642994,
entity: entity1,
tag_ids: ['test','1'],
owners: [],
account_id: asd1233124124,
integration_type: integartionType1
}
```

I want to get docs where fields name, description, tag_ids contains the partial match from this text `HEY_TEST_TABLE`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `bool query` with three match queries inside a `should` clause to search for documents where the fields `name`, `description`, or `tag_ids` contain a partial match from the text.

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "name": "HEY_TEST_TABLE" } },
        { "match": { "description": "HEY_TEST_TABLE" } },
        { "match": { "tag_ids": "HEY_TEST_TABLE" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can use [the multi-match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query.

Comment: For example: 
`{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "name": "HEY_TEST_TABLE" } },
      ]
    }
  }
}
`
Not working, still bringing me names not relevant docs that not contains the string...

Comment: Also multi-match return docs with no relevant name...

Comment: try to use keyword field type.